# VBA Userform - floating frame - move frame object with each movement of mouse or scroll

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have a userform with buttons within a frame to save the workbook and zoom in/out. This frame is currently at the bottom of the userform but what I was attempting to do was to have a floating frame on the left side of the form.

The 'left' position of the frame would be fixed but the frame would continue to remain in the same 'top'  position as the user scrolls up or down the form.

I have the following code when the userform is initialized:

```
.Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * .Height)
```

I placed this code for the frame into the various MouseMove and Scroll operations but it doesn't move the frame once it is in position in the first instance.

Any help is appreciated and I understand that this may not be possible or be an effective solution for the end user. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Excel is event based. If you want a floating frame at a certain position within a form you need to capture ALL possible events which can occur and possible move the "floating" frame from the position where you want it to be. Afterwards, you need to adjust the position of the frame within your form generate the illusion that it is floating when - in fact - the frame is re-aligned within the form each time that the form is changing or scrolled.

This might be somewhat difficult to achieve and can generate a lot of code. But maybe an alternative solution can be to have more than one form open and shown to the user at the same time? The "floating" frame can be one form which you place in the top left corner of Excel and another form is shown in the center of Excel. Based on certain events and actions of the user this can have an impact on form1, form2 or the underlying Excel workbook (as you see fit).

To use several forms within Excel simply show the form to the user with the option Modal = false.

```
UserForm1.Show(false)    
UserForm2.Show(false)
```

Hope that helps.